# Extracting metadata of image in python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, metadata

I am writing the code for extracting metadata of images in python but it does not show any output.

```
pip install Pillow
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
# path to the image or video
imagename = "image.jpg"

# read the image data using PIL
image = Image.open(imagename)

# extract EXIF data
exifdata = image.getexif()

# iterating over all EXIF data fields
for tag_id in exifdata:
    # get the tag name, instead of human unreadable tag id
    tag = TAGS.get(tag_id, tag_id)
    data = exifdata.get(tag_id)
    # decode bytes 
    if isinstance(data, bytes):
        data = data.decode()
    print(f"{tag:25}: {data}")
```

I tried different methods but it does not work as I tried with OpenCV library cv2 as well
The expected output is the metadata of the image file

Comment: How do you know the image contains EXIF data? Please click [edit] and paste the output from `exiftool YOURIMAGE.JPG`

Comment: All EXIF data is metadata but not all metadata is EXIF data.  EXIF is a specific type of metadata, not a general term.  The data you are looking for might be IPTC IIM/Legacy data or XMP data (which includes IPTC Core/Ext).

Comment: As I am a beginner so don't know the details. Thank you your comment helps.